# How do I draw a 3D model using sharpDX?

Tags: draw, sharpdx, 3d-model

How do I draw a 3D model using sharpDX? Most examples on the web just say that I can't without some other library.  My models are in .fbx format and the build action properties are ToolkitModel.

Comment: +1 I am also interested, as I was always using the XNA Framework and I am also searching for alternatives

Answer (score -1):

SharpDX used to come with a namespace called SharpDX.Toolkit.Graphics. In the more recent versions it has been deprecated in favour of Monogame and Xenko. https://github.com/sharpdx/Toolkit

The code to draw a model looks as follows:

```
using SharpDX.Toolkit;
using SharpDX.Toolkit.Content;
using SharpDX.Toolkit.Graphics;
```

...

```
protected override void LoadContent() {
//...
model = Content.Load<Model>("mymodel");
//...
}
```

...

```
protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime){
//...
var view = Matrix.LookAtRH(cameraPos, modelPos, cameraUp);
var proj = Matrix.PerspectiveFovLH(fov, aspect, near, far);

var world = //arbitrary model position.
Matrix.Scaling(0.1f)*
Matrix.RotationY(Util.fPi/2)*
Matrix.Translation(modelPos);

model.Draw(GraphicsDevice, world, view, proj);
//...
}
```